# groovy/xml - get a a specified attributs in a node

Tags: xml, groovy

I want to know how to get a xml node with only childs with a specified attribut:
For exemple if I have a node like:

```
<mode name="name" >
    <data dataname="STO">data</data>
    <file dataname="FO">file</file>
    <file dataname="STO">file</file>
    <file dataname="STO">file</file>
    <data dataname="FO">data</data>
    <data dataname="STO">data</data>
    <data dataname="FO">data</data>
</mode>
```

I want to get the same structure with only the childs with dataname attribut equal to "STO":

```
<mode name="name" >
    <data dataname="STO">data</data>
    <file dataname="STO">file</file>
    <file dataname="STO">file</file>
    <data dataname="STO">data</data>
</mode>
```

I tried this code but I don't get what I expected:

```
def xmlTest = new XmlParser().parse(xmlFile)
def nodetest= xmlTest.mode.find {it.'@name' ==  'name'}
nodetest.children().findAll { it.'@dataname'== "STO"}
```

the result is:

```
<data dataname="STO">data</data>
<file dataname="STO">file</file>
<file dataname="STO">file</file>
<data dataname="STO">data</data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go:

```
def txt = """<mode name="name" >
    <data dataname="STO">data</data>
    <file dataname="FO">file</file>
    <file dataname="STO">file</file>
    <file dataname="STO">file</file>
    <data dataname="FO">data</data>
    <data dataname="STO">data</data>
    <data dataname="FO">data</data>
</mode>"""
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(txt)
xml.depthFirst().findAll{ it.@dataname == 'STO' }
```

With `XmlParser` it will work as well.

**UPDATE**

Code below returns xml with filtered content:

```
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def txt = """<mode name="name" >
    <data dataname="STO">data</data>
    <file dataname="FO">file</file>
    <file dataname="STO">file</file>
    <file dataname="STO">file</file>
    <data dataname="FO">data</data>
    <data dataname="STO">data</data>
    <data dataname="FO">data</data>
</mode>"""
def xml = new XmlParser().parseText(txt)
xml.depthFirst().findAll{ it.@dataname == 'STO' }.each {
    xml.remove(it)
}
XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

Comment: I have the same result as my code: I only get the list of the childs and I want to get also the "mode" node

Comment: But is doesn't have an attribute called `dataname`. Also `mode` is the root. You need some xml filtering?

Comment: I know it doesn't have 'dataname' attribute, that's why I don't know how to do. What to you mean with xml filtering?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is it what You're looking for?

Comment: Yes thanks, this is what I want to have. 
I just replace it.@dataname == 'STO'  by it.@dataname != 'STO' in your code.